# How to convert GML to features in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, development, arcgis-engine

How to convert GML to features and features to GML i ArcObjects? 
We are building an application where we want to communicate with a service with GML but natively in our stand-alone application we want to use features and shapefiles.

Update: I have an ArcGIS Server so I could use that a bridge so I could use thatas a bridge beween the service and the client.

Comment: did you ever decide on what your doing?

Comment: We ended up round-tripping to our database (SQL Server 2008 R2) where we converted and stored it as a geometry in the database. So we did not solve it on the client side, but @Petr-k answer is correct you can use the Data Interoperability Extension to convert GML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only supported way that I know of, though indirect (via intermediate feature class storage), is to use the **Data Interoperability extension**. The API documentation does include, among other things, [a short sample on GML conversion](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004np000000).

Alternatively, I might look into GDAL/OGR libray for which you'll be able to find .NET bindings. In any case, dealing with the conversion on your own is likely to be a major task.

Comment: I will take a look at the Data Interoperability extension.

Answer (score 4):

1. You have my complete admiration for attempting this. You may be insane, but I'm discounting that possibility.
2. Since you say ArcObjects / ArcEngine, I'm assuming a .NET implementation
3. I would definitely start [here](http://oegeo.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/importing-the-gml-321-namespace-into-net/). Somehow, you need to get generated classes from the XSD, and while you *could* do it yourself for whatever subset you need, it's gonna hurt. If there's any way to use LINQ (and it appears there is), I'd try that route.

If you can give a few more details on what you're trying to accomplish (r/o? r/w?), I suspect that someone can probably give you more specifics. What you're attempting is a largish, but not insurmountable problem.

Oh, and one quick (obvious in retrospect) question - does the server you're talking to generate WSDL? If so, then you should be able to get VS2008 or 2010 to consume that directly, making life much more pleasant.

Edit: Add specifics from minor experimentation:

Starting from the link [previously](http://oegeo.wordpress.com/2008/04/10/importing-the-gml-321-namespace-into-net/), I was able to generate C# classes using XSD. This generates classes that will fail at runtime due to the problem of XSD & .NET not generating strongly typed lists correctly. I also tried the suggestions / fixes from [this post](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2009/04/opengis-with-net-20-and-wcf.html), just to see what's changed. I'm unconvinced that changing the underlying data types from double/int, etc. to string is the greatest idea ever, but it *should* work. In both cases the command to generate classes is:

```
xsd.exe gml.xsd ..\..\xlink/1.0.0\xlinks.xsd ..\..\iso\19139\20070417\gmd\gmd.xsd ..\..\iso\19139\20070417\gco\gco.xsd ..\..\iso\19139\20070417\gss\gss.xsd ..\..\iso\19139\20070417\gts\gts.xsd ..\..\iso\19139\20070417\gsr\gsr.xsd /classes
```

And yeah, it's ugly. It also assumes that you've downloaded the entire set of schemas from OpenGIS.net (available [here](http://schemas.opengis.net/SCHEMAS_OPENGIS_NET.zip)), which you've got to have to resolve all the references.

A quick comparison of the two resulting sets of classes shows surprisingly few differences (the original data type in parenthesis after the name of the changed member:

```
 DirectPositionType.Text (double)
 DirectPositionListType.Text (double)
 GridType.axisLabels (NCName)
 ParameterValueType.integerValueList (integer)
 MeasureListType.Text (double)
```

So, worst case, if you really needed to, you might want to use the "fixed" version of 3.2.1, and then update those few members to use custom serialization to get a more strongly typed implementation instead of simply using strings.

Comment: 1. I would not be so sure :)
2. Yes, .Net 
3. That's one way I could go, but not without making sure that there aren't any build-in ways in arcobjects to do this.

Comment: I don't know of anything in ArcObjects that deals with GML. As far as I know, you're on your own to build the mapping between the two technologies, which is a daunting enough task. I should have mentioned that looking into the .NET Topology Suite might be of some benefit; if they're not supporting GML, it might be worthy of an extension into that project.

Also meant to ask - do you have control over the server side as well, or just your own stand-alone client?

Comment: Yes and no, I have access to our arcgis server but not to the service servicing the GML.